# iPhone/iPad : table view scroll crash in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hi all I want to show more than `120 images` in tableview its runs fine in simulator but crash in device (ipad).
logs show memory warning but I am releasing perfectly I don't know why I get this message and crash. Images comes from server I am using following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FullTableViewCell *cell = (FullTableViewCell *)
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    loadNibNamed:@"FullTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {         
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (FullTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *dic = [socketConnection().imageInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int imageId = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    UIImage *image = [socketConnection().serverImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *IMMage = [self scaleImage:image toResolution:740];


    cell.cellIMage.image = IMMage;
    cell.addButton.tag = imageId;
    cell.zoomOutButton.tag = imageId;
    [cell.zoomOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(_ZoomOut:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265+(3.14159265/2));

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

plz anybody help me where i am wrong..

Comment: Can you run the instruments and see which one of them are leaking?

Comment: Could there be a problem in `scaleImage`?

Comment: i used instrument no problem on that ...

Answer (score 0):

Implement:

```
if (cell) {
[cell setImage:nil];
[cell setImage://image];
// Put ALL cell code here
 }
```

and release:

image and IMMage and FullTableView and topLevelObjects and dic before

```
    return cell;
```

AND FINALLY AND MOST IMPORTANTLY:

also analyze you're project to see for leaks